# Как сохранить сохранить текст из textbox в label после перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

Есть `textbox` и `label`. Нужно из `textbox` передать значение в `label`.

Делаю так:

```
label1.text = textbox1.text;
```

Нужно, чтобы при следующем заходе на сайт значение в `label` осталось (сейчас оно обнуляется). Как его сохранить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если надо сохранять значение между заходами на сайт, то есть всего два варианта:

1. Хранить значение на клиентской стороне, в cookies

   ```
   protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       this.label1.Text = this.textbox1.Text;

       var cookie = new HttpCookie("someName", this.label1.Text);
       cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

       this.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
   }

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (!this.IsPostBack)
       {
           var cookie = this.Request.Cookies["someName"];
           if (cookie != null)
           {
               this.label1.Text = cookie.Value;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Хранить значение на серверной стороне, в долгоживущем хранилище (базе данных). Как-то идентифицировать пользователя при следующем заходе на сайт, и показывать ему соответствующее значение.

Обычно идентификация сводится опять же к установке cookie, но не с самим значением, а с каким-то id пользователя, так что для случая хранения одного значения проще не заморачиваться и просто использовать первый вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Сохранить состояние Bы можете несколькими способами (я так понял речь идет об WebForms):

- Использовать состояние представления ASP.NET; (*свойство `ViewState`*)
- Использовать состояние элемента управления ASP.NET;
- Определить переменную уровня приложения; (*класс `HttpApplicationState` и свойство `Application`*)
- Использовать объект кэша; (*свойство `Context`*)
- Определить переменные уровня сеанса; (*свойство `Session`*)
- Использовать cookie-наборы. (*класс `HttpCookie`*)

Вот пример использования ViewState'a:

Например по какому то событию сохраняем значение `TextBox.Text`

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["TextBox"] = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

А при следующей загрузке страницы читаем его и устанавливаем состояние `Labal`

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = (string)ViewState["TextBox"];
}
```

Все эти вещи достаточно хорошо для новичка описаны в книге Эндрю Троелсена *Язык программирования C# 5.0 и платформа .NET 4.5* (34 глава)

Comment: ViewState (лежиит на странице. закрыл страницу - вьюстейт потерян), ControlState (то же самое), Application (живет до перезапуска приложения, общее для всех пользователей), сессия (20 минут), Кэш (как повезет) не слишком подходят для хранения значения между заходами на сайт. К тому же label1.Text и так хранит свой текст во ViewState, так что пример совсем не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 0):

По-возможности используйте ответы выше, но в случае безисходности:

```
Session["value"] = TextBox1.Text;
label1.Text = Session["value"];
```