# Хранение промежуточных данных ASP.NET MVC

Tags: база-данных, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

При разработке сайта, тестирующего знания пользователей, возникла дилемма как хранить данные вида: кол-во верных ответов, кол-во ошибок и т.д.

Создать модель свойства которой будут соответствовать требуемым данным и сохранять их в TempData, а затем при каждом ответе пользователя их доставать, изменять и снова сохранять в TempData:

```
class Result 
{
  int errors {get;set;}
  .....
}
ActionResult Answer(.....)
{
  var res = (Result)TempData["Results"];
  res.errors++;
  ....
  TempData["Results"] = res
  ....
}
```

либо создать таблицу в БД и при каждом ответе пользователя обращаться к ней и изменять данные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Используйте `HttpCookie`.
2. Писать в БД.

Вот более [детально](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443803/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-textbox-%D0%B2-label-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B/443823#443823).

Comment: Это или...или? И, как я понимаю, первый вариант предпочтительнее, верно?

Comment: @alexey_mankov, или первое или второе. Можно использовать оба. Всё зависит от долгожительности результатов. Если вы хотите хранить результат очень долго то лучше использовать запись в БД, если хранить до того момента пока юзер не почистить куки то первый, если на момент сессии то можно использовать `Session`